# React production build failing with useContext and keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am using gatsby and the build seems to be failing in this useContext file:

```
Gatsby build
```

**Building static HTML failed for path "/components/DarkThemeContext/DarkThemeContext/"**

DarkThemeContext.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react"

const DarkThemeContext = React.createContext({
  darkMode: false,
  setDarkMode: () => {},
})

export const DarkThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false)

  return (
    <DarkThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        darkMode: isDark,
        setDarkMode: setIsDark,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DarkThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useDarkThemeContext = () => useContext(DarkThemeContext);

export default useDarkThemeContext;
```

It fails in this file during build but the exact error it spits out is:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {darkMode, setDarkMode}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I am not sure how and why this is it picking this up as children

**Edit: included code for DarkThemeProvider render**

gatsby-browser.js

```
import React from "react"

import { DarkThemeProvider } from './src/pages/components/DarkThemeContext/DarkThemeContext'

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <DarkThemeProvider>{element}</DarkThemeProvider>
}
```

Edit: include code where context is accessed for darkMode

navDrawer.jsx

```
const { darkMode } = useDarkThemeContext()

  const darkModeStyling = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: darkMode ? "dark" : "light",
    },
  })

...

    <ThemeProvider theme={darkModeStyling}>
...
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: It looks like you've *some* component attempting to render your context value. Is there a stacktrace for this error to tell you where the error occurs?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you render the `DarkThemeProvider` Component?

Comment: Hi I have added relevant code for you guys :)

Comment: @DrewReese added relevant code for you

Comment: @Japsz added relevant code for you

Comment: No, I think we need to see the code that is accessing the context (*and apparently rendering the context value*), not providing it... `DarkThemeProvider` is clearly only rendering the `children` prop passed to it.

Comment: Added for you - thanks :)